# Integer Permutation GA Fitness Function

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

After developing an initial population of random integers, I am now facing the problem of linking the individual of each population to the fitness function and also the arguments to give to the fitness function. I have the following creation and fitness functions, but when I run the GA from the workspace it is giving the following error "Failure in initial user-supplied fitness function evaluation. GA cannot continue":

```
function pop = facilities_arrangement(NVARS,FitnessFcn,options)
  %Creates a population of facility arrangement permutations.

  totalPopulationSize = 50;
  n = NVARS;
  pop = cell(totalPopulationSize,1);
  for i = 1:totalPopulationSize
  pop{i} = randperm(n);
  end



function scores = facility_layout_fitness(CR,distances)
  % Custom fitness function for the facility layout problem.

  % Calculates the fitness of an individual. The fitness is the total product
  % between the closeness rating of the facilities and the distances 
  % travelled from one facility to another from their centroids 
  % by using the rectilinear distance.  
  pop = cell(totalPopulationSize,1);
  scores = zeros(size(pop,1),1);
  totalPopulationSize = 50;
  for i = 1:totalPopulationSize
  order = pop{i};
  A = CR(order,order);
  TCF = sum(A(:).*distances(:));
  scores(i) = TCF;
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the ga function without giving an intial population.

But, if you want to use one (and I agree that it's a good idea) you have to be sure that your initial population satisfies the problem constraints, and that it's a good enough solution to start. The way you are doing it, just generating a random population, does bring anything to the solver.

You can just call:

```
x = ga(fitnessfcn,nvars)
```

If it is a facility location problem, as it seems, you should use some kind of greedy algorithm to try to generate a good feasible solution to feed your genetic algorithm.